# sharepoint content query link to the source page?

Tags: sharepoint, url

If i can get the title of the page where contents are coming from, how can i get the url of  the same page with that title?

```
 <div class="custom_posttitle"> 
        <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.CallPresenceStatusIconTemplate"/> 
        <a href="{$SafeLinkUrl}" title="{@LinkToolTip}"> 
          <xsl:if test="$ItemsHaveStreams = 'True'"> 
            <xsl:attribute name="onclick"> 
              <xsl:value-of select="@OnClickForWebRendering"/> 
            </xsl:attribute> 
          </xsl:if> 
          <xsl:if test="$ItemsHaveStreams != 'True' and @OpenInNewWindow = 'True'"> 
            <xsl:attribute name="onclick"> 
              <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$OnClickTargetAttribute"/> 
            </xsl:attribute> 
          </xsl:if> 
          <xsl:value-of select="$DisplayTitle"/> 
        </a> 
    </div>
```

IN the XSLT, sth like this?

```
<div>
<a href="{@Linktothesourcepage}">READ MORE</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
<a href="{$SafeLinkUrl}" title="{@LinkToolTip}">
```

from the xslt you posted already has the link to the page.

Comment: Thank you. You helped me out here even though it could have been a small thing for you, it meant big to me. I am new to XSLT.